# Eclipse overview web/image browser

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, browser

Say I have this block of comment in my class1.java (or .js or whatever) and I am using Eclipse to edit it

```
// bla comment comment
// screenshot at http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png
```

Is there a plugin that enables me to hover over the URL and launch an overview web browser on top of my editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the `CTRL` key and click on it - you'll find Eclipse has that functionality built right in!

Comment: ha thanks!! now if only Eclipse can pop up an overview of it without opening a new tab... :)

Comment: Well, looks like you could probably implement it via a SWT snippet...Check here for some examples: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser